# Sum of elements inside a vector C++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, iterator, sum

I am trying to calculate the sum of all floats in a vector. The user-inputs are the number of elements in the vector and the floats. For some reason, the sum is printed out as 3.01734...

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float n, temp, sum;              // integer variables declaration
    vector<float> nums;             // declaration of "nums" vector
    cin>>n;                        // number of elements in the vector "nums"

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){      
        cin >> temp;            // user input for "temp" variable
        nums.push_back(temp);  // adds(pushes) "temp" to "nums" vectors
    }                         

    for(int j=0; j<(short)nums.size(); j++){ 
        sum+=nums.at(j);   // adds the "j" element of "nums" vetor to sum
    }                   

    cout << sum;        // outputs the sum

    return 0;
}
```

> Edit:
>   This code doesn't work because "sum" is not initialized. We need to initialize the "sum" to 0.0 manually because otherwise, it will store memory "garbage" or if we set it to 0 it will round the "sum" (which is a floating point number) to a whole number (integer).

Comment: `(short)nums.size()`? What's the point of this?

Comment: Also `sum` is never initialized, so `sum+=nums.at(j);` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: casting the unsigned to signed

Comment: You forgot to initialize `sum` properly to `.0`.

Comment: Why do you need to cast the size? And in a lossy way at that? `short` is smaller than `size_t` on most platforms

Comment: [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)?

Comment: `sum` is uninitialised, and the first thing done to it is to add something to it.   The behaviour is therefore undefined.

Comment: @VlatkoStojkoski When replying to someone, make sure to begin your comment with `@username`. Otherwise we might not get a notification and might never see your reply. (You get notifications unconditionally, because the comments are under your question.)

Answer (score 2):

When you don't initialize variables, they start off with "garbage" value, which is a value that's been in their memory address. So when you iterate over the vector, and increase it each time by each value, you've actually started counting from the random number you started with, instead of 0. Here's how it should be (untested):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float n = 0, temp = 0, sum = 0; // initialized variables as 0.
    vector<float> nums;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> temp;
        nums.push_back(temp);
    }

    nums.resize(n); // to be honest I don't really understand why this is needed

    // note: you can use the letter i again, when you declare a variable inside a scope, 
    // it's only declared for that scope.
    for(int j=0; j<(short)nums.size(); j++){
        sum+=nums.at(j);
    }

    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```